# How do you solve $x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^2y+z$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The given: $x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+2y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=x^2y+z$
Transform the PDE into an ODE:
$ \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{dy}{2y} = \frac{dz}{x^2y+z}$.
From the first two equations obtain $ \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{dy}{2y} \rightarrow φ_1= \frac{y}{x^2}$
But I have no idea to find the other. Please enlighten me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Auxiliary equation:

$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{2y} = \frac{dz}{x^2y+z}$$

Solving $\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{2y}$

We have $x^2=cy\tag{1}$ for some constant $c$.

Solve $$\frac{dy}{2y} = \frac{dz}{x^2y+z}$$

$$\implies \frac{dy}{2y} = \frac{dz}{cy^2+z}\quad [\text{using (1)}] $$

$$\implies \frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{cy^2+z}{2y}$$

$$\implies \frac{dz}{dy} -\frac{z}{2y}=\frac{c}{2}y$$

Which is easy to solve, linear first order ode.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Hmm sorry i hve been trying to solve it. But its still a mess. Can u finish it for me

Comment: Find integrating factor $\mu(y) =e^{\int-{\frac{1}{2y}dy}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$

Comment: $\frac{z}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{c}{3}y^2+d\sqrt{y}$

Comment: Put the value of $c$ and....

Comment: @chiichill008 If this answer (or other answer ) is helpful, then you can give reward by accepting (by ticking ✅).

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{dx}{x} = \dfrac{dy}{2y} = \dfrac{dz}{x^2y+z}$$
For the second constant of integration:
$$\dfrac{ydx^2}{2x^2y} = \dfrac{x^2dy}{2x^2y} = \dfrac{dz}{x^2y+z}$$
$$\dfrac{dx^2y}{4x^2y} =  \dfrac{dz}{x^2y+z}$$
$$\dfrac{u+z}{4u} =  \dfrac{dz}{du}$$
Where $u=x^2y$. This is a first order DE. Substitute $z=tu$:
$$1+t=4t'u+4t$$
$$4t'u=1-3t$$
This DE is separable.